# Yoda Speak Api. Is it the key or code?

Tags: json, api, mashape

I am trying to use the Yoda speak api. Here is my fiddle of it:

- http://jsfiddle.net/Dansker/tdhnmmye/

  ```
  $.ajax({
      url: 'https://yoda.p.mashape.com/yoda', // The URL to the API. You can get this by clicking on "Show CURL example" from an API profile
      type: 'GET', // The HTTP Method
      data: {sentence: $("#boxArea").val()}, // Additional parameters here
      datatype: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
          alert(data);
      },
      error: function (err) {
          alert(err);
      },
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization", "<RvyROurVRvmshRzDcAtXABdytvkDp1MtroWjsnXo8Dcs9Dq6SB>"); // Enter here your Mashape key
      }
  });});});
  ```

I think the code all works but I keep getting 403 errors saying my key does not work. I keep resetting my key but it keeps saying that it does not work. Is it the key or something else? Also the "yoda speak" will be displayed as alert?

Comment: Remove the < > operators from your key. Also assuming this is your actual mashape key you wouldn't want to post it here for everyone to see. As a side note I have been using the above API for a while. Combined with Mashape issues and the actual API endpoint down time I had significant issues and so switched to http://funtranslations.com/api/yoda and it is working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but have you tried removing the outer angle brackets?

Try changing this:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization", "<RvyROurVRvmshRzDcAtXABdytvkDp1MtroWjsnXo8Dcs9Dq6SB>");
```

To this:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization", "RvyROurVRvmshRzDcAtXABdytvkDp1MtroWjsnXo8Dcs9Dq6SB");
```